# Trying to execute a function from html in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm working with Angular 8 and when I press a button need to execute a javaScript function but that doesn't work.

I have a method that I found here how to import external javaScript.

The objetive of the button is to hide a navbar.

I have the code like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-admin',
  templateUrl: './home-admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './home-admin.component.css',
    './Style/style.css'
  ]
})
export class HomeAdminComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js');
    this.loadScript('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    this.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js');

  }

  public loadScript(url: string) {
    const body = <HTMLDivElement>document.body;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = '';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;
    script.defer = true;
    body.appendChild(script);
  }

  click($event) {

    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
      $('#sidebar, #content').toggleClass('active');
      $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
      $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
  }

}


<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Scrollbar Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-header">
                    <h3 align="left">CHROMAE PROJECT</h3>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div id="content">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" type="submit" (click)="click($event)">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                                <span>MENÚ</span>                               
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I try to put the function into the html but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I recommend you go back to the tutorial at angular.io as you seem to have some large gaps that can't be covered in an SO answer

Comment: The first thing you need to do is remove jQuery

Comment: Why use jQuery with Angular for a so simple thing?You can achieve this just using Angular features. +1 to remove jQuery as@mwilson said

Comment: here https://angular.io/guide/user-input you can see how to add events in your html elements.

Comment: Add a click event listener to the button based on which you can toggle a variable that can control the hiding/displaying of your navbar.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't want to use jQuery for this. It is a huge anti-pattern on the entire reason why someone would go with Angular in the first place.

In your case, you need to first remove all your jQuery code and bind the `(click)` event to an actual method in your `Component`.

Secondly, Angular Components are made from HTML Fragments, not a full on HTML Document. With that being said, you can omit `html` tags.

Lastly, *do not* load scripts by inserting them into the DOM like you are doing. If you need an external library, install it via `ng add` or `npm install` and load it into your code by `import` statements. If you don't do this, it will not be able to picked up by webpack.

Here's an example of what your code should look like:

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-admin',
  templateUrl: './home-admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './home-admin.component.css',
    './Style/style.css'
  ]
})
export class HomeAdminComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  myClickEvent(evt: MouseEvent): void {
    alert('The button was clicked');
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3 align="left">CHROMAE PROJECT</h3>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" type="submit" (click)="myClickEvent($event)">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                                <span>MENÚ</span>                               
                            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should go spend a couple hours working through the [Angular Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) example. It will cover some of these fundamental concepts.

Comment: Ok, i undestand what you saying about not using javaScript like that, but how can i hide that sidebar executing myClickEvent ??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do inside the click event?

Comment: Im trying to remove the navbar and move the button on left side. i put screenShoot

Comment: You need to put your screenshot in your question. You provided your screenshot as an answer which it is not. But, you want to use `ngClass` for your use case. That gives you the ability to apply a class based on a condition